# Error implementing stripe payment in deployment (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, heroku, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe payment system in my Heroku web application. Below you can see a html file which has a 'Purchase' button, which calls the javascript function 'MyFunction()' when clicked. After this happens, the javascript function calls the create_checkout_session() function in Flask (the Python file), which returns a session checkout ID to the javascript function, which redirects to the payment page. For some reason, the below process works perfectly on localhost, but fails when I deploy to Heroku. I get an error 500 in Heroku for some reason.

[image]

html file

```
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction()" id="stripePay">Purchase!</button>
    </div>
  </section>


  <script>
    function myFunction() {


    //stripe
    // Get Stripe publishable key
      // Initialize Stripe.js
      const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_zcqqggPiGsbFA49H0BE4Mxj200AyZDDWnN');

      // new
      // Event handler
        // Get Checkout Session ID
        fetch("/create-checkout-session")
        .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          // Redirect to Stripe Checkout
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout(data)
        })
    };
</script>
```

Python file

```
@app.route("/create-checkout-session")
def create_checkout_session():
    domain_url = "http://localhost:5000/"
    stripe.api_key = stripe_keys["secret_key"]

        # Create new Checkout Session for the order
        # Other optional params include:
        # [billing_address_collection] - to display billing address details on the page
        # [customer] - if you have an existing Stripe Customer ID
        # [payment_intent_data] - capture the payment later
        # [customer_email] - prefill the email input in the form
        # For full details see https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

        # ?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} means the redirect will have the session ID set as a query param
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            success_url=domain_url + "success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            cancel_url=domain_url + "cancelled",
            payment_method_types=["card"],
            mode="payment",
            line_items=[
                {
                    "name": "T-shirt",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "amount": "2000",
                }
            ]
        )
        return jsonify({"sessionId": checkout_session["id"]})
```

EDIT:

Here is the error I get when clicking the 'Purchase' button on my deployed Heroku app.
[image]

Comment: You should check your server logs to find any details around that 500. Alternatively you can check your Stripe dashboard's logs to see if the 500 came from Stripe's end when creating the Checkout Session.

Comment: @PaulAsjes Stripe logs seem to indicate 200, which are OK. Seems to be a problem on my end. It works perfectly on localhost though, not sure why!

Comment: try using https as payment processing should be secure. This is one of the requirements for PCI compliance and there is no way to avoid this.

Comment: @novice why would you have `domain_url` set to localhost while on herokuapp? I don't work with python, so i don't know if its overridden by other value, but just curious if that is causing issues.

Comment: @Pirate I just left that there for the 'success_url' and 'cancel_url'. I'll change it later, once the actual Stripe checkout implementation is working. By the way it's not the reason for the issue, I tried with default url's like 'https://www.google.com/'. I think the answer at the bottom is getting closer to the root of the issue, but still haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 3):

From the logs screenshot, I am guessing this is because the processing time of your application is too long. Check that the service time is 383 ms

```
service=383ms
```

But Heroku does a timeout for the connection if it exceeds 300ms [(link)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). That's why your application works locally but not on Heroku. In other words, you have to return some response before the timeout kicks in.

You can try these methods:

1. Add a `--timeout 400` option in the Procfile. Eg: `web: gunicorn app:app --timeout 400`
2. Try to implement streaming response. For example, in Flask, you can use this code: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/ . You can find a similar one for your use case of the first option does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Kebby! I tried the timeout thing, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. I've updated my original post to include the console, which displays the error I get when clicking the 'Purchase' button on my deployed Heroku app.

Comment: It seems that the `fetch("/create-checkout-session")` is taking too long, hence the error statement says `"Syntax Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"`, since it is sending improper JSON response. Can you comment out the fetch statement and check if it is deploying properly on Heroku?

Comment: I think you're right! I replaced the fetch statement with `console.log("Hello world!");` and it's printing it out every time I press the 'Purchase' button! Wonder if there's a way I can solve my problem though :/

Comment: Can you break down the fetch statement into multiple smaller statements? I faced a similar problem and implemented the streaming template from Flask. So the thing is you need to send a response back to Heroku within 300 ms. Suppose, the fetch statement is taking 350ms, breaking it up into two parts may take 175ms and 175 ms each. This is below the Heroku timeout limit and thus, your app will work successfully on Heroku.

Comment: any ideas on how I can go about breaking up the fetch statement? I'm quite a beginner to JS and web dev. Hence why I'm using Flask to build the app as I'm proficient in Python.